# How to convert a string array to an int array?

Tags: java

How do I convert a string like:

```
"114 214 219"
```

Into an an int array so I have something like this stored in my int array:

```
int[] couseNumbers = int[3];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     courseNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(/*get int in the string array*/);
}
```

Comment: I don't get what your problem is? The code you have should work just fine.

Comment: Well, except for the fact that `couseNumbers` and `courseNumbers` are different names...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the String into an array first.

```
String[] stringArray = "114 214 219".split(" ");
```

Then in the loop you can access that array:

```
courseNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please mark my answer as solution if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 streams.

```
 List<Integer> courseNumbers = Arrays.stream("1123 213 23"
  .split(" ")).map(x-> Integer.parseInt(x))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks but It'd be better with an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String s = "1 2 3";
String array[] = s.split(" "); //Splits the Array by spaces
int a[] = new int[array.length]; //Makes new int array
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]); //Converts String to int
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Answer above by Eduardo Dennis will not work as string cannot convert to int directly. You can do something like this.

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    String s = "114 214 219";
    String [] courseNumbers = s.split(" ");
    Integer [] intArray = new Integer[courseNumbers.length];
    for(int i= 0; i < courseNumbers.length; i++){
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(courseNumbers[i]);
    }

 }
```