# How can I copy a String to a int array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I have a string that contains numbers and I would like to put this numbers in a int array.

The format is like this:

```
String s = "234, 1, 23, 345";

int[] values;
```

What i want:

```
values[0]=234

values[1]=1

values[2]=23

values[3]=345
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java read this and try yourself

Comment: Step one: [Split the string into an array.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/1828486). Step 2: [Parse the strings and move to a new array.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5585779/1828486)

Comment: Same class as [How to convert a string array to an int array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42842961/205233)?

Comment: `int[] values = Pattern.compile(", ").splitAsStream(s).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using a String utility

```
String[] strings= s.split(",");
```

and then loop over strings and add them to the int array using something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++){
    values [i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` the string by comma, `iterate` through tokens and add them into another array by converting each token into `integer`, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "234, 1, 23, 345";
    String[] tokens = s.split(",");
    int[] numbers = new int[tokens.length];
    for(int i=0 ; i<tokens.length ; i++){
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i].trim());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java8 :

```
String s = "234, 1, 23, 345";
String array[] = s.split(", ");
Stream.of(array).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the String

```
String s = "234, 1, 23, 345";
String array[] = s.split(", ");
int a[] = new int[array.length];
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Split, for-loop, and parse to int

```
String s = "234, 1, 23, 345";
String[] splittedS = s.split(", ");
int[] values = new int[splittedS.length];

for (int i = 0; i < splittedS.length; i++) {
    values[i] = Integer.parseInt(splittedS[i]);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```

and if you are able to use streams **java8**

```
String[] inputStringArray = s.split(", ");
Integer[] convertedREsult = Arrays.stream(inputStringArray).map(Integer::parseInt).toArray(Integer[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(convertedREsult));
```